# How does a 120V wall outlet accommodate to a 240V electric dryer?

Tags: ac

I am beginner learning electronics and I started to learn AC.

I've learnt that a US wall outlet provides 120V, however, I've googled that electric dryers are usually rated at 240V.

So how would a US wall outlet that is rated at 120V, accommodate to an electric dryer that is rated at 240V?

Comment: It doesn't. The US has 240V outlets too - they're just less common and only used for specific appliances in specific location (like electric dryers).

Comment: they use different outlets that are connected to 240V

Comment: People without that kind of knowledge should not install electrical devices. Invite professionals.

Comment: Fully electric dryers (those which use electricity to dry the clothes) are always 240.   Dryers that use gas still need electricity to run the motors, but they're all 120V

Comment: Fully electric dryers are available for 120V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S., power comes into the residence as 120/240 V single split phase. This means that there is a neutral and two 120 V lines. Picture it as a center tapped transformer secondary, the center tap is neutral and the ends of the secondary are the 120 V hot lines.

The wall outlets are connected between neutral and one of the 120 V lines. The breaker panel is connected so that some outlets are on one of the 120 V lines, some on the other, so the total load tends to be split evenly between them.

For large appliances such as a dryers, electric stoves, and large air conditioners, the power is connected across the two 120 V lines to give 240 V. There are different types of outlets for 120 and 240, and even some different type outlets for different current ratings.